# http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease 404

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to build a docker image.  I'm getting this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
```

Apparently the resource does not exist.  What should I do?
Thanks in advance,
-Jmt

Comment: Use another mirror -

Comment: Hmm. Local mirror of Ubuntu hasn't `InRelease` file for `trusty` version! Maybe Replacing `InRelease` with `Release` solves the problem.

Comment: @SuB I'm interested by what you say, but ... how to make that replacement? Thanks.